# Htop shows half cores at 100% cpu usage after power on, but no processes are runing

Tags: cpu-usage

I am using an Ubuntu 20.04 server, but it starts up with 50% CPU use without any process running. I tried many ways such as rebooting and upgrading OS, including [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/653292/htop-shows-one-core-at-100-cpu-usage-but-no-processes-are-using-much-cpu), but in vain.
can anyone help me find why this happens and resolve this please?

[image: htop after each reboot]

Comment: try pressing (capital!) `K` to show the kernel threads. Your system is probably doing something like synchronizing a raid array in the background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148036/discussion-between-giacomo-catenazzi-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: Is it half of the cores, or is it the half-cores (not the full-cores, or ⅔-cores).

Comment: sorry for my poor languages, it is 50% us in top command and 16 out of 32 cores are 100% (see in the picture i posted).

Comment: FYI, i am new to Ubuntu and this, so sorry i have no reputation to continue this in chat. i am hoping a simple way to resolve this.

Comment: I'm facing exactly the same problem. Have you solved it?

Comment: sorry, i had no clue about it, this could be firmware or virus related. so i just reinstall the OS and problem solved.